# Wordpress―move from domain.com to localhost/dir

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress multisite installation which would like to move from the productive domain to my localhost, so the the installation should be altered in a way that `somedomain.com` becomes `localhost/dirname`.

Right now I have these settings in `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false );
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/dirname/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'SUNRISE', 'on' );
```

and the `.htaccess` looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Right now an infinite redirect loop starts to: `http://localhost/dirname/wp-signup.php?new=localhost`

Which settings do I have to make?

Greetings,
philipp

**EDIT**

If `WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE` and `MULTISITE` is set to `false` this problem does not occur, but since I need to access the page as multisite this is no option.

Answer (score 0):

If you're moving a wordpress installation, after importing the database into your local mysql server. Edit your wp-config.php file, changing the 'DB_NAME' 'DB_USER' 'DB_PASSWORD' 'DB_HOST' to reflect the settings for your local database. Then use this script http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ to search for your domain name and replace it with localhost/dirname. After that you login and save your permalinks.

Comment: the database is not the issue. I should have mentioned that this is already done

Comment: can you access wp-admin?

Comment: you could just clear your htaccess file and go to the wordpress permalink settings and resave your permalinks settings.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: no, does not change anything. Except  the line to upload files it is quite the same as the code above.

Comment: btw. I made a test install on my server where the host is something like: subdomain.domain.com and everything works fine there. So I just guess that multisite cannot deal with a non-domain host?

Comment: what url do you have there? Did you install a subdirectory based multisite?

Comment: mine isn't in a subdirectory

Answer (score 0):

JUst checked, to install WordPress MU in localhost on subdomain/subdirectory, you need to set up virtual hosting in Windows system.

Go to C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc and open the file “hosts” with notepad (you need to have administrator privilege to edit the file. Right click the Notepad application in the Start menu and select Run As Administrator).

Insert in the line

`127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain`

to the end of the file. Save and close the file.

If you are using mac os, you can follow this http://wpdreamer.com/2013/08/how-to-setup-a-localhost-wordpress-sub-domain-multisite-environment/

You could change it to localhost.com, then edit your wp-config file to reflect that, also change the values in the database using http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Comment: Thanks again! I tried all that before. In fact I had to change the multisite modus from subdomain to subdirectory, the causes a lot of issues…